# psql variables in included scripts

Tags: postgresql, scripting, psql, postgresql-9.3

UPDATE:  This specific problem is not related to psql included scripts.  Variables in the included scripts ARE interpolated as expected.  Actual problem results from the use of psql variables inside $$ quotes in SQL function definitions and is [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259703/are-there-any-escaping-syntax-for-psql-variable-inside-postgresql-functions).

I am using psql variables to set some parameters (table names, values) from the command line in a rather long SQL script.  The script has become too long and I splitted it into several parts and included them into the main script using `\ir subscript.sql` syntax.  However, variables from the main script are not passed to the subscripts.  This is strange because documentation says that `\i file` is an equivalent of typing file on the keyboard, i.e., the script environment should be preserved.

Is there a simple way to pass variables to the included scripts in psql?

I am using psql version 9.3.1.

Comment: What you describe should just work. Can you show a reproducible example?

Comment: Oops! I tried to create a reproducible example and realized that the problem is actually that variables are not interpolated inside $$ quotes in SQL function definitions.  In the included scripts psql variables are interpolated correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `--variable=` at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Eg.

```
psql -d somedb -U someuser -f yourscript.sql --variable=Foo=foobar
```

In your script you could have:

```
UPDATE sometable SET somecol = :Foo;
```

Comment: with --variable=Foo=foobar :Foo will be visible in the yourscript.sql, however if I call any other script from yourscript.sql using `\i another.sql`, then :Foo won't be visible inside another.sql

Comment: Ah, I glossed right over that point in the original question. I suppose you could work around this by using a scripting language to create the scripts, eg. Bash, and pass that down into the sub-scripts.

Comment: I tried to create a reproducible example and realized that the problem is actually that variables are not interpolated inside $$ quotes in SQL function definitions.  In the included scripts psql variables are interpolated correctly.